# Recommended levels for Chapter 5?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I'm about to start Chapter 5, but I'm not sure if I'm at the right level. 
Here's my party:

Avatar, Lv. 15
Elma, Lv. 15
Lin, Lv. 15
Irina, Lv. 14

And can anyone recommend a good grinding spot if so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, my party's levels are 19, 18,18, and 16 right now, and I really don't think that's enough. The targets for the beginning part are level 16s, but they're surrounded by 15-22s that you have to deal with beforehand. I'd say level up a bit more if you can, because this is no fun the way I'm doing it.

As far as grinding goes, I'd suggest you do any missions that you feel like you're up to at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you can defeat a level 23 non-blatta enemy comfortably, you'll be comfortable doing this mission.

That doesn't mean you need to be able to do this as you start the mission.  Much of the mission involves a large area of level 18-20 enemies with a high spawn rate which you could use to level up.

If those are too hard, you could go back to the level 4 mission area and grind Prone there.

Perhaps grinding isn't your thing: instead, you could go do some affinity missions.